# What is the name of this 26 pin connector?

Tags: connector, identification

I am trying to reverse engineer this applied precision actuator (I'll ask different questions as I do so)

To get started I would like to know the name of the 26 pins connector! (oh and if you also know the 5 pins connector name too?)

After hours of google image search I cannot find it!

[image: Connector]

Comment: Off-hand I'd say it looks like a SCSI connector of some sort. Although it's probably not being used for SCSI here of course.

Comment: what is the product/device?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's called a HP26 (Half Pitch) connector. There don't seem to be a lot of sources for it though, so good luck finding one.

[image: HP26 connector]

Comment: Thanks !! 

Alright, let's look for some chinese vendor on Ebay ^^